# Defalult no of Thread in Process in Asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

how many number of thread per process default  in the system.thread.threadpool in asp.net 3.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

250 worker threads per processor under .NET 3.5

Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx?ppud=4).

Answer (score 1):

default size is 250. ...worker threads per processer

1000 I/O threads

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx